# How can I use encoding="UTF-8" inside a data frame including arabic words in R?

Tags: r

I am making a data frame in R with Arabic names as follows:

```
D<-data.frame(x=c("محمد","علی","رسول"),y=c(1,1,1))
D
```

But when I run my code I see the output in UTF-8 codes as follows:

```
                                 x y
1 <U+0645><U+062D><U+0645><U+062F> 1
2         <U+0639><U+0644><U+06CC> 1
3 <U+0631><U+0633><U+0648><U+0644> 1
```

How can I add encoding=UTF-8 to my code in order to see the data frame D in arabic?

Comment: Try `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Arabic")`

Comment: This is cross-posted from R-Help where the locale was "persian" (with lower case initial).